# Расположение img

Tags: css3, html5

Как я понимаю всё лучше обернуть в конструкцию figure c figcaption.
Нужно расположить картинки как показано ниже и что бы при добавлении новой картинки можно было выбрать в какой ряд её вставлять.
[image: Нужно расположить картинки как показано ниже.]

Answer (score 1):

Не понимаю где сложность в данном вопросе

> если что то не ясно спрашивайте

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

.items {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 10px;
}

.item p {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x150" alt="">
      <p>Описание</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="">
      <p>Описание</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="">
      <p>Описание</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x100" alt="">
      <p>Описание</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```